# How to get case insensitive unique fields using unique fields in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
options(orders.map { |order| ["#{order['name']} (#{order['id']})", order['name']] }.uniq )
```

1. AUS00012 FUND1
2. AUS00012 fund1
3. AUS00056 fund3
4. AUS00056 FUND3

This returns both uppercase and lowercase records. How can I get only uppercase names?

Comment: Can you please add sample values in question?

Comment: try options(orders.select { |order| ["#{order['name']} (#{order['id']})", order['name'].upcase] }.uniq )

Comment: Its not working. Displays both upper and lower case records @RaviPrakash

Comment: then try options(orders.select { |order| ["#{order['name']} (#{order['id']})", order['name'] == order['name'].upcase] }.uniq )

Comment: This changed the value!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a block to `uniq` and invoke `downcase` (or `upcase` as you prefer) on the object being yield:

```
options(
  orders.uniq { |order| order['name'].downcase }
        .map { |order| ["#{order['name']} (#{order['id']})", order['name']] }

)
```

Maybe you can try modifying your query:

```
# Using Postgres
Order
  .select('DISTINCT(UPPER(name)), *')
  .order('UPPER(name)')
```

Comment: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 359ms (ActiveRecord: 10.8ms)



NoMethodError - undefined method `downcase' for #<Array:0x00007f3cec623038>:
  app/helpers/orders_helper.rb:229:in `block in options_for_funds'
  app/helpers/orders_helper.rb:229:in `options_for_funds'

Comment: Swap the order of the functions being used. See the updated answer, also my recommendation would be to tweak your query instead using `uniq` for that.